# Error: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "data". Expected Object, got Array

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

Hola estoy aprendiendo Vuejs y para ello estoy realizando una consulta a la base de datos donde los items del menu los extrae directamente de la bd y todo funciona perfectamente, pero en la consola aparece el siguiente error, que repito no afecta el funcionamiento pero es incomodo verlo ahi, espero puedan ayudarme a encontrar la solucion:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "data". Expected Object, got Array found in

---> <VxAutoSuggest> at resources/js/src/components/vx-auto-suggest/VxAutoSuggest.vue
       <SearchBar> at resources/js/src/layouts/components/navbar/components/SearchBar.vue
         <VsNavbar> at vsNavbar.vue
           <TheNavbarVertical> at resources/js/src/layouts/components/navbar/TheNavbarVertical.vue
             <Main> at resources/js/src/layouts/main/Main.vue
               <App> at resources/js/src/App.vue
                 <Root>
```

el codigo del controlador encargado de publicar el json es el siguiente:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Files;
use App\Pages;

class NavbarSearchAndPinlistController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $query = pages::where('user_id', '1');
        $pages = $query->paginate();
        /*if(request()->wantsJson())
        {*/
            return $pages;
        /*}
        return view('partials.failed');*/
    }
}
```

y el codigo del componente con el error es este:

```
<template>
    <div class="flex">
        <div class="search-full-container w-full h-full absolute left-0 top-0" :class="{'flex': showFullSearch}" v-show="showFullSearch">
            <vx-auto-suggest
                ref="navbarSearch"
                :autoFocus="showFullSearch"
                :data="navbarSearchAndPinList"
                search_key="title"
                background-overlay
                class="w-full"
                inputClassses="w-full vs-input-no-border vs-input-no-shdow-focus"
                icon="SearchIcon"
                placeholder="Explore Vuexy..."
                @input="hnd_search_query_update"
                @selected="selected"
                @closeSearchbar="showFullSearch = false">

                <template v-slot:group="{ group_name }">
                    <p class="font-semibold text-primary">{{ group_name | title }}</p>
                </template>

                <!-- Pages Suggestion -->
                <template v-slot:pages="{ suggestion }">
                    <div class="flex items-end leading-none py-1">
                        <feather-icon :icon="suggestion.icon" svgClasses="h-5 w-5" class="mr-4" />
                        <span class="mt-1">{{ suggestion.title }}</span>
                    </div>
                </template>

                <!-- Files Suggestion -->
                <template v-slot:files="{ suggestion }">
                    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                        <div class="flex items-center">
                            <div class="img-container w-8 mr-3 flex">
                                <img :src="get_ext_img(suggestion.ext)" :alt="suggestion.file_name" class="responsive">
                            </div>
                            <div class="leading-none mt-1">
                                <p class="mb-1">{{ suggestion.file_name }}</p>
                                <small>by {{ suggestion.from }}</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <small>{{ suggestion.size }}</small>
                    </div>
                </template>

                <!-- Contacts Suggestion -->
                <template v-slot:contacts="{ suggestion }">
                    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                        <div class="flex items-center">
                            <img :src="suggestion.img" :alt="suggestion.name" class="w-8 h-8 mr-3 rounded-full">
                            <div class="leading-none mt-1">
                                <p>{{ suggestion.name }}</p>
                                <small>{{ suggestion.email }}</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <small>{{ suggestion.time }}</small>
                    </div>
                </template>

                <!-- No Items Slot -->
                <template v-slot:noResult="{ group_name }">
                    <div class="flex items-center">
                        <feather-icon icon="InfoIcon" svgClasses="h-5 w-5" class="mr-4" />
                        <span>No results found.</span>
                    </div>
                </template>

            </vx-auto-suggest>

            <div class="absolute right-0 h-full z-50">
                <feather-icon
                    icon="XIcon"
                    class="px-4 cursor-pointer h-full close-search-icon"
                    @click="showFullSearch = false" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <feather-icon icon="SearchIcon" @click="showFullSearch = true" class="cursor-pointer navbar-fuzzy-search ml-4" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import VxAutoSuggest from '@/components/vx-auto-suggest/VxAutoSuggest.vue';
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        components: {
            VxAutoSuggest
        },
        data() {
            return {
                navbarSearchAndPinList: [],
                showFullSearch: false,
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            axios.get('/api/v1/pages')
                .then(res => {
                    this.navbarSearchAndPinList = { pages: {key:'title', data: res.data.data}};
                });
        },
        computed: {
            get_ext_img() {
                return (ext) => {
                    if (ext == "doc")      return require(`@assets/images/file-icons/doc.png`)
                    else if (ext == "jpg") return require(`@assets/images/file-icons/jpg.png`)
                    else if (ext == "xls") return require(`@assets/images/file-icons/xls.png`)
                    else if (ext == "pdf") return require(`@assets/images/file-icons/pdf.png`)
                    else return require(`@assets/images/file-icons/doc.png`)
                }
            },
        },
        methods: {
            selected(item) {
                item.pages ?  this.$router.push(item.pages.url).catch(() => {}) : null
                this.showFullSearch = false;
            },
            hnd_search_query_update(query) {
                // Show overlay if any character is entered
                this.$store.commit('TOGGLE_CONTENT_OVERLAY', query ? true : false)
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme a encontrar que es lo que esta mal, gracias!

Comment: Me parece que deberia ser res.data o verifica: this.navbarSearchAndPinList = { pages: {key:'title', data: res.data.data}};

Comment: Lo que sucede es que si uso res.data no va a recibir las variables el componente ya que el json está paginado por lo que tenemos que acceder a res.data.data

Comment: En la función data() estás devolviendo un array para ese atributo `navbarSearchAndPinList: [],`, y recién pasa a ser un objeto después de la llamada de axios, sin embargo lo estás pasando como prop al componente `<vx-auto-suggest :data="navbarSearchAndPinList"`, que aparentemente espera un objeto. Prueba definir ese atributo como un objeto desde el inicio `navbarSearchAndPinList: {},`, o si eso no funciona, prueba con un objeto con la misma estructura que espera el componente, pero sin los datos `navbarSearchAndPinList: { pages: {key:'title', data: [] }}`